# Convert timedelta to total seconds

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I have a time difference

```py
import time
import datetime

time1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.gmtime()))
...
time2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.gmtime()))
diff = time2 - time1
```

Now, how do I find the total number of seconds that passed? `diff.seconds` doesn't count days. I could do:

```py
diff.seconds + diff.days * 24 * 3600
```

Is there a built-in method for this?

Comment: @RestRisiko - you're right. Still, it's useful to have the question on Stack Overflow, so the next time me, or someone else, Googles for it, he has a good answer as the top result.

Comment: We can discuss alternative definitions of "good" later; please read my answer before you run away :)

Comment: There are multiple issues with computing `time1`, and `diff` in your code. To get the current utc time as a naive datetime object, use `datetime.utcnow()` instead. To understand why you should use UTC instead of the local time to find the difference see [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279). `time.monotonic()` could be preferable to find elapsed time between events (instead of `time.time()` or `datetime.utcnow()`).

Answer (score 628, accepted):

Use [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds).

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.timedelta(seconds=24*60*60).total_seconds()
86400.0
```

Comment: If somebody still needs to be compatible with 2.6: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318348/how-can-i-extend-pythons-datetime-datetime-with-my-own-methods/14214646#14214646 for how to extend datetime.timedelta with the new method yourself.

Comment: datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(time2-time1) in Python3.6

Comment: `(time2-time1).total_seconds()` in python 3

Answer (score 12):

You have a problem one way or the other with your  `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(time.gmtime()))` expression.

(1) If all you need is the difference between two instants in seconds, the very simple `time.time()` does the job.

(2) If you are using those timestamps for other purposes, you need to consider what you are doing, because the result has a big smell all over it:

`gmtime()` returns a time tuple in **UTC** but `mktime()` expects a time tuple in **local time.**

I'm in Melbourne, Australia where the standard TZ is UTC+10, but daylight saving is still in force until tomorrow morning so it's UTC+11. When I executed the following, it was 2011-04-02T20:31 local time here ... UTC was 2011-04-02T09:31

```
>>> import time, datetime
>>> t1 = time.gmtime()
>>> t2 = time.mktime(t1)
>>> t3 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t2)
>>> print t0
1301735358.78
>>> print t1
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=9, tm_min=31, tm_sec=3, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=92, tm_isdst=0) ### this is UTC
>>> print t2
1301700663.0
>>> print t3
2011-04-02 10:31:03 ### this is UTC+1
>>> tt = time.time(); print tt
1301736663.88
>>> print datetime.datetime.now()
2011-04-02 20:31:03.882000 ### UTC+11, my local time
>>> print datetime.datetime(1970,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=tt)
2011-04-02 09:31:03.880000 ### UTC
>>> print time.localtime()
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=20, tm_min=31, tm_sec=3, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=92, tm_isdst=1) ### UTC+11, my local time
```

You'll notice that t3, the result of your expression is UTC+1, which appears to be UTC + (my local DST difference) ... not very meaningful. You should consider using `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` which won't jump by an hour when DST goes on/off and may give you more precision than `time.time()`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. For the purpose I'm using right now, a difference of even a few hours every now and then isn't important, but I'll be sure to check this out in the future when I write something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

More compact way to get the difference between two datetime objects and then convert the difference into seconds is shown below (Python 3x):

```
from datetime import datetime
        
time1 = datetime.strftime('18 01 2021', '%d %m %Y')
    
time2 = datetime.strftime('19 01 2021', '%d %m %Y')

difference = time2 - time1

difference_in_seconds = difference.total_seconds()
```

Comment: This is no different to the 10 year old accepted answer.

Comment: Erm, the accepted answer does not use Python 3's `time2 - time1` syntax, only the comments underneath it do. So it is a bit different...

Answer (score 0):

You also can divide a timedelta by another timedelta for a specific unit. As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) states:

> `timedelta.total_seconds()`
>
> Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration. Equivalent to `td / timedelta(seconds=1)`. For interval units other than seconds, use the division form directly (e.g. `td / timedelta(microseconds=1))`.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3:

```
import datetime
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
# do something
total_seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds()
```

Answer (score -7):

You can use mx.DateTime module

```
import mx.DateTime as mt

t1 = mt.now() 
t2 = mt.now()
print int((t2-t1).seconds)
```