# Compare launch time of EC2 instance and current time in python

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I extract the launch_time from EC2 instance, it returns a unicode string like this:

> 2014-12-22T08:46:10.000Z

I use dateutil parser to convert it to datetime with

```
launch_time = parser.parse(instance.launch_time)
```

so I get lunch_time after converted like this:

> 2014-12-22 08:46:10+00:00

And I want to compare this launchtime with current time to see how long this instance has been running.

I get current_time with:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

and I get it like this:

> 2014-12-22 11:46:10.527010

Now I have two timestamps, I have this function

```
def timeDiff(launch_time, current_time):
    running_time = current_time - launch_time
    return running_time.seconds/60
```

I expect the result would be 180 minutes (3 hours). But I got this error:

> TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

I think there's obvious difference between these two timestamps. I need to compare exactly date and time to see how long it has been running. I couldn't find a proper way to solve this. Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: unrelated: use `running_time.total_seconds()` instead of `.seconds`.

Comment: related: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: It's useful to be aware that the OP assumed that the time diff is < 1 day and that the code will not work for time diff > 1 day, because `.seconds` does not count days. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522031/convert-timediff-to-total-seconds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the timezone you want from `now()` like the following:

`current_time = datetime.datetime.now(launch_time.tzinfo)`

Then your subtraction should work, as both of the times will be timezone aware.

Edit: I should note that you can put whatever timezone object you want in `now()` and it will work just fine. `now()` will convert the time to whatever timezone you pass. The important part is to simply ensure that if you're adding/subtracting datetime objects that they both have timezones (or they both lack timezones).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked just fine with launch_time.tzinfo. I got the expected result. Thanksss!

Comment: @LouisTran: another way is to remove `tzinfo`: `(datetime.utcnow() - launch_time.replace(tzinfo=None)).total_seconds()` but @alienth solution is better because it works even if `launch_time` is not in UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

```
import boto.ec2
from dateutil.parser import *
import subprocess
import datetime


instance_id = subprocess.check_output(['curl', '-s', 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id'])

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2',aws_access_key_id='Your_Key', aws_secret_access_key='Your_Secret')

reservations = conn.get_all_reservations(instance_ids=[instance_id])

for r in reservations:
    for instance in r.instances:
        lt_datetime = parse(instance.launch_time)
        lt_delta = datetime.datetime.now(lt_datetime.tzinfo) - lt_datetime
        uptime = str(lt_delta)
        print(uptime)
```