# Conversion of datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-web-services, boto

Trying to use datetime to get an age of ec2 instance by comparing launch_time to current time. All working fine by using format below:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(instance.launch_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

Unfortunately I've got an one with 0 microseconds, so getting an error about not matching format:

```
time data '2015-03-16T03:21:05Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

> 2015-03-16T03:02:12.910Z
>
> 2015-03-16T03:21:05Z - this one is problematic
>
> 2015-03-25T09:19:34.018Z

Any idea how to get around this? It looks like `datetime` is the easiest way to get this sorted but if there are quicker way of doing that, happy to see other options. FYI, comparision has to be done up to hour, so don't care about seconds. Thanks.

Comment: If you only want up to the hour, why not e.g. `strptime(instance.launch_time[:13], "%Y-%m-%dT%H")`?

Comment: Or you catch that exception...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare launch time of EC2 instance and current time in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601551/compare-launch-time-of-ec2-instance-and-current-time-in-python)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks for quick response, working perfectly :)