# Convert datatime format to sampletime

Tags: python, time-series

Working on Python, I need to convert an array of datetime values into sample times, because I want to treat the corresponding time of the time series as sampletime [0..T].

`[2013/11/09 14:29:54.660, 2013/11/09 14:29:54.680, ... T]` where T> 1000. So I have an array of >1000 date time values, pretty big

I come up with the following code:

```
tiempos= [datetime.strptime(x,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for x in csvTimeColum]
sampletime= [(t- tiempos[0]).microseconds/1000 for t in tiempos]
```

This piece of code seem to work well, but I have batches of 1000 samples within the signal:

```
[0,20,...,980,0,20,...,980,0,20,...,980,...]
```

So, my resulting signal is not a continuos one. How do I properly do this conversion in order to keep a continuous signal? Anybody has a good idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What is the problem? You would need to share some more data!

Comment: @AntonvBR look at the last array, with the resulting sample times. It starts at 0 over and over again. So, when you plot the signal with the new array of sample times, it is a mess. I am checking the pandas library, but I don't get a clear idea on how to do it

Comment: oh ofc, it because microseconds reset

Comment: @fran_jo: what time origin do you want? Apparently you tried with the origine of a time series and you did not like it. Why don't you just take an arbitrary date (datetime) that you would convert the same?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I don't think I completely understand... the origin of my data is the first value of the array, this has to be the sample time 0.  But the problem I faced was the "cycles" on the resulting array (batches of 1000 samples from 0..980 in an array of X>1000 samples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use total_seconds() which also works for timedeltas:
[Convert TimeDiff to total seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522031/convert-timediff-to-total-seconds)

```
sampletime= [(t- tiempos[0]).total_seconds()*1000 for t in tiempos]
```

Working example:

```
import datetime
csvTimeColum = ["2013/11/09 14:29:54.660", "2013/11/09 14:29:54.680"]
tiempos= [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for x in csvTimeColum]
sampletime= [(t- tiempos[0]).total_seconds()*1000 for t in tiempos]
sampletime # [0.0, 20.0]
```

Comment: Thank you @AntonvBR. This is what I was looking for!