# How to extract seconds from datetime.timedelta

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime, timedelta

I have a list of dates and hours. For each date, I would like to extract only the seconds value.

Here is my script :

```
import datetime

format_string = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = ['2021-01-29 15:15', '2021-01-29 15:50', '2021-01-29 17:00']
date = [(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format_string)-now) for i in date]
print(date)
```

And here is the output :

```
[datetime.timedelta(seconds=7269, microseconds=211221), datetime.timedelta(seconds=9369, microseconds=211221), datetime.timedelta(seconds=13569, microseconds=211221)]
```

I just want the seconds for the three elements of the list 'data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
date = [(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format_string)-now) for i in date]
```

To

```
date = [(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format_string)-now).seconds for i in date]date = [(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format_string)-now) for i in date]
```

Comment: I am glad to help! You can also use ´total_seconds`, as its shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522031/convert-timedelta-to-total-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

It works with :

```
date = [(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format_string)-now).seconds for i in date]
```