# convert timedelta to seconds

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I calculated the duration in my dataframe, but I want to get the duration in seconds instead of what it gives (`0 days, 00:10:25` and so on):

```
df['duration'] = df['end_date'] - df['start_date']
df.head(2)
    started_at  ended_at    start_date  end_date    duration
0   2021-01-23 16:14:19 2021-01-23 16:24:44 2021-01-23 16:14:19 2021-01-23 16:24:44 0 days 00:10:25
1   2021-01-27 18:43:08 2021-01-27 18:47:12 2021-01-27 18:43:08 2021-01-27 18:47:12 0 days 00:04:04
```

I tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522031/convert-timedelta-to-total-seconds), but I'm not really sure how to do it right, nothing works; for example I tried this:

```
df['duration'] = datetime.timedelta.total_seconds(df['duration'])
```

but it says

```
TypeError: descriptor 'total_seconds' for 'datetime.timedelta' objects doesn't apply to a 'Series' object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the total_seconds method. However, you'd need to access that method via the datetime accessor `dt`.

```
>>> df['duration'].dt.total_seconds()
```

However, if series `Duration` are strings/object- you should do use pd.to_timedelta

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try running apply on your Series

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(datetime.timedelta.total_seconds)
```

From your error. It is stating that you are trying to run it on a Series